# in python webapp2 how put a __init__ in a handler (for get and post)

Tags: python, webapp2

How can I create initialization code?
When I put the `__init__` constructor always tell me that parameters are wrong.

Also please someone gave a example also using `__new__` and one using `super()` and why should we use or not use them.

```
import webapp2

class MainHandler( webapp2.RequestHandler ):
    def __init__( self ):
        #initialization code/vars
        x = 1

    def get( self ):
        #code for get here
        self.response.write( x+1 )

    def post( self ):
        #code for post here
        self.response.write( x+2 )
```

app = webapp2.WSGIApplication ( [ ('/', MainHandler) ], debug=True )

Comment: There are other questions about when to use `__new__` and `super()` here on SO already, please do search for those.

Comment: sorry for the "def" and "self"... was a cut/past thing... already corrected...

Answer (score 14):

Finally got it...
The problem is that overriding "webapp2.RequestHandler" requires special special handling

from the webapp2 manual:

If you want to override the webapp2.RequestHandler.**init**() method, you must call
webapp2.RequestHandler.initialize() at the beginning of the method. It’ll set the current request,
response and appobjectsasattributesofthehandler. 
Example:

```
class MyHandler(webapp2.RequestHandler):
    def __init__(self, request, response):
    # Set self.request, self.response and self.app.
    self.initialize(request, response)
    # ... add your custom initializations here ...
    # ...
```

...and that's it...
now works as expected
;-)

Comment: It's probably obvious, but I had to double-check - `self.initialize(request, response)` won't call any parent handlers' constructors, so you will need to explicitly do that (and move `self.initialize(request, response)` into the parent).  Call the parent with `super(subclassNameHere, self).__init__(request, response)`.

Answer (score 2):

If you aren't passing any arguments or including any of your own code in the `__init__` method, there's usually no need to even create one. You'll just use `webapp2.RequestHandler`'s `__init__` method.

If you *do* need to make one, you still have to call `webapp2.RequestHandler.__init__`:

```
class theHandler(webapp2.RequestHandler):
    def __init__(self, your_arg, *args, **kwargs):
        super(theHandler, self).__init__(*args, **kwargs)

        self.your_arg = your_arg
```

Comment: I'm using webapp2 and code is this ---->

    class theHandler( webapp2.RequestHandler ):
        def __init__( self ):
            #def some class shared vars
    (...)

the error is ---->
TypeError: __init__() takes exactly 1 argument (3 given)
INFO     2013-03-13 23:30:43,937 dev_appserver.py:3104] "GET /rotx HTTP/1.1" 500 -

Comment: Sorry for the confusing text... the error is :
TypeError: __init__() takes exactly 1 argument (3 given)
INFO     2013-03-13 23:30:43,937 dev_appserver.py:3104] "GET /rotx HTTP/1.1" 500 -

Comment: @ZEE: Post your actual class definition and how you're initializing it.

Comment: Just updated the code very simplified just to expose the issue... i'm sure i'm missing something here...

Comment: @ZEE: You have to read through a Python tutorial. You're missing out on a lot of core concepts: http://learnpythonthehardway.org/book/

Answer (score 0):

You need to have a `self` variable in all the functions within your class. You need to include this variable for the function to work within your class.

A good explanation to the need of the `self` variable in each function within a class can be found [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2709821/python-self-explained).